# Implementing EJB timer service on a datasource in an application server

Tags: timer, ejb, datasource, wildfly-8

I am migrating my application from JBoss 6 AS to Wildfly 8.2.0. AS. As a part of it, I need to migrate EJB timer service defined on the configured datasource in JBoss 6 AS.

I have gone through the EJB timer service study material and got that it is used to do a job on a schedule basis.

`Implementing EJB timer service in datasource in an application server` - what does this mean ? In wildfly AS, there is a file `timer-sql.properties` which requires a syntax change according to the database employed and an entry in `standalone-full-ha.xml` as mentioned below.

```
timer-service thread-pool-name="timer" default-data-store="clustered-store">
            <data-stores>
                <database-data-store name="clustered-store" datasource-jndi-name="java:/TestDB" partition="timer"/>
            </data-stores>
        </timer-service>
```

I would like to understand more on the same and hence, can anyone please explain what the EJB timer service configured on a datasource in an application server does and how it works at a high level. Also, please suggest any link that explains the same. Thanks.